# How to download a file object to the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Within a route:

```
app.get('some-route', async (req, res) => {
    // ...
}
```

I have a file object (`file`) which looks like:

[image]

Now I want to download this.

Currently I am doing:

```js
app.get('some-route', async (req, res) => {
    const file = //...
    res.write(file.data.buffer,"binary");
    res.end();
}
```

This works, but gives a file without an extension named `download` (by adding the extension manually I can check it works).

How can I set the name and extension of the file? (or is there an entirely different better way to download a file like this?)

Comment: How are you accessing this file? Is there a route involved? Please show a little more code.

Comment: @zero298 Just updated with info, apologies for missing it initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [download](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp#:%7E:text=The%20download%20attribute%20specifies%20that%20the%20target%20%28the,name%20of%20the%20file%20after%20it%20is%20downloaded.) attribute in html file to download file for user.

Comment: So this helped me find the solution, although does rely on some other disconnected knowledge, it is `<a href="data:<%= file.mimetype %>;base64,<%= file.data.buffer.toString('base64') %>" download="<%= file.name %>">Download</a>` in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use express module [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). To send a file to the server, you need to wrap it in FormData

```
var fd = new FormData()
fd.append("file", file)

fetch("/express-server", { method: "POST", body: fd })
```

To recive file on server, you have to follow the guide for `multer`

Comment: I am asking about downloading to a user, not uploading to a server.